# Are built-in mongo functions faster than functions in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Is it worth using MongoDB built-in functions to filter data? I think the functions in MongoDB are faster because the database is mostly written in C++ and is designed to be as performant as possible. Besides, to create POJO, the database has to parse it from JSON, on the other hand, mongo functions probably work on a low level with bson.
For example, what is better in terms of performance and memory consumption: get the full array of items and slice it using Java, or get the sliced array using $slice from Mongo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always better to reduce the amount of data that is transferred from the database to the application logic as much as possible from a performance point of view. It is a waste of ressources to transfer a huge amount of data only to reduce it later on by filtering or selecting the fields that you are interested in. So definitely filter data with MongoDB functions.

The main factor is not so much performance of the functions, but the amount of data that has to be transferred over a slow network. In comparison to the transfer over the network, the execution speed of C++ vs. Java is not that relevant.

Also, you typically have less hardware ressources in the application layer (e.g. not so much RAM) than you have in a DB cluster. So even if you'd manage to transfer a huge database to the application layer, it would exhaust the ressources of the application layer.